# How to safely modify a mutable slice reference field?

Tags: rust, lifetime

Let's consider this struct:

```
pub struct A<'a> {
    inner: &'a mut [u8],
}
```

I would like to modify inner so that it refer to a subslice of itself:

```
pub fn func (arg: &mut A) {
    arg.inner = &mut arg.inner[0..2];
}
```

But I get a *lifetime mismatch error*. I have tried this:

```
pub fn func <'x,'a> (arg: &'x mut A<'a>) where 'x:'a {
    arg.inner = &mut arg.inner[0..2];
}
```

this function compiles but... apparently if I use this function twice I get a *cannot borrow twice* error:

```
pub fn func2(arg: & mut [u8]){
    let mut a = A{inner: arg};
    func(&mut a);
    func(&mut a); //Error borrow twice
}
```

I'am a two week old rustacean, I'd like also to understand why the two version of `func` are wrong.

Comment: The duplicate applied to your problem: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5ed78f1d05a871c2639134280f4bf3b6). Your case is actually simpler than the one in the linked question, and there's no way the temporary empty slice can be observed from outside `func` (odds are good it gets optimized away entirely).